# One index weirdly missing in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm importing an excel file into pandas. It contains mixed text and numerical data; what I need to do is iterate over a column containing text with a view to processing that text. However, when I do, I get a key error:

```
KeyError: 145831
```

The thing is, there is no reason this value should be missing. The values before and after it are present:

```
hashtags['tweet'].loc[145829:145834]

145829    Internet Marketing Made Easy. Stop By:   https...
145830               @sbxr Lol. How’s the fishing up there?
145832    @HelloMD_com @TreatWellHealth Tinctures are or...
145833    @MikeBloomberg We would like to suggest that y...
145834    @mannydr Yeah the whole re-labeling thing is w...
```

For some reason, 145831 just isn't there. I tried reindexing the dataframe, but the KeyError remains.

Can anyone suggest a workaround, or why this might might be happening? Note that the excel served an error notice when I opened the sheet, saying it repaired some of the data––this is likely relevant.

Comment: have you tried reset_index(drop=True) and try the same?

Comment: Yes, this is the answer! I'd confused reindex with reset_index. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there should be 2 reasons - index values are already in excel file and some rows are missing or some rows was removed after reading excel file.

Solution is generate default index:

```
hashtags = hashtags.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks––this is the answer I was looking for!